# What does dnn.js SetCookie do

Tags: dotnetnuke

Our application is in  Dotnetnuke 4.9.2 version,

In our recent security audit they found that in file DNN.js it sets some cookies in SetCookie method,

I need some info on why DNN.js uses this file for ?

Can I comment this out, if so what would be the complications >

Any references would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really upgrade to a newer version of DotNetNuke as there are a lot of security issues that have been resolved in the 4 or 5 years since DNN 4 was last released.

The cookies are likely setting things like "Visibility" on modules that can be expanded or collapsed, or setting cookies for if you have the Control Panel in View/Edit/Layout mode

Comment: Our project is in maintenance mode, we do not have any plans to upgrade to a latest version, If i comment of setting of cookies in this file (Dnn.js) will there be any problems to the USERS who are using it.

Comment: Sure there is a chance there will be problems as you're changing core functionality of DNN

Comment: I tried to debug this, I see the setCookie being called only when a module is minimized or maximized, my question is how would this effect the normal user if I comment out the code, a normal user cannot have access to alter the modules right ?

Comment: That is the visibility I was referring to. You can likely comment that out without an real repercussions, assuming you aren't trying to allow people to do that. I always turn that functionality off on my DNN sites.